# Create Source from Lagom/Akka Kafka Topic Subscriber for Websocket

Tags: scala, websocket, apache-kafka, akka-stream, lagom

I want my Lagom subscriber-only service to subscribe to a Kafka Topic and stream the messages to a websocket. I have a service defined as follows using this documentation (https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/MessageBrokerApi.html#Subscribe-to-a-topic) as a guideline:

```
    // service call
    def stream(): ServiceCall[Source[String, NotUsed], Source[String, NotUsed]]

    // service implementation
    override def stream() = ServiceCall { req =>
      req.runForeach(str => log.info(s"client: %str"))
      kafkaTopic().subscribe.atLeastOnce(Flow.fromFunction(
        // add message to a Source and return Done
      ))
      Future.successful(//some Source[String, NotUsed])
```

However, I can't quite figure out how to handle my kafka message. The `Flow.fromFunction` returns `[String, Done, _]` and implies that I need to add those messages (strings) to a Source that has been created outside of the subscriber.

So my question is twofold:
1) How do I create an akka stream source to receive messages from a kafka topic subscriber at runtime?
2) How do I append kafka messages to said source while in the Flow?

Comment: `req.runForeach(str => log.info(s"client: %str"))` will exhaust your entire input stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the service API of Lagom. If you're trying to materialize a stream from the body of your service call, there's no input to your call; i.e.,

```
def stream(): ServiceCall[Source[String, NotUsed], Source[String, NotUsed]]
```

implies that when the *client* provides a `Source[String, NotUsed]`, the service will respond in kind. Your client is not directly providing this; therefore, your signature should likely be

```
def stream(): ServiceCall[NotUsed, Source[String, NotUsed]]
```

Now to your question...

This actually doesn't exist in the scala giter8 template, but the java version contains what they call an [autonomous stream](https://github.com/lagom/lagom-java.g8/blob/23a77c733ff7705d303569ef1777efac0212996c/src/main/g8/%24name__norm%24-stream-impl/src/main/java/%24package%24stream/impl/%24name__Camel%24StreamServiceImpl.java#L34) which does approximately what you want to do.

In Scala, this code would look something like...

```
override def autonomousStream(): ServiceCall[
  Source[String, NotUsed], 
  Source[String, NotUsed]
] = ServiceCall { hellos => Future {
    hellos.mapAsync(8, ...)
  }
}
```

Since your call isn't mapping over the *input* stream, but rather a kafka topic, you'll want to do something like this:

```
override def stream(): ServiceCall[NotUsed, Source[String, NotUsed]] = ServiceCall { 
  _ => 
    Future {
      kafkaTopic()
        .subscribe
        .atMostOnce
        .mapAsync(...)
    }
}
```